# Relation between automorphic representations and Laplacian eigenvalues

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $G=SL(2, \mathbb{R})$. I would like to understand how and why automorphic forms correspond to automorphic representations, and how general is this fact (for other groups).

Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $G$, $X = \Gamma\backslash G$ and $Y=X/K \simeq \Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}$ for a compact subgroup $K$. The group $G$ acts on $X$, hence on the right on functions on $X$ or on $Y$.

Take an automorphic form $\phi$ (i.e. an eigenfunction of the Laplace operator on $Y$). Introduce the space of $G$-translates of $\phi$, that is $V_\phi$ the span of the $g\phi = \phi(g^{-1}\cdot)$ for all $g\in G$. This is a $G$-invariant subspace, and in fact an irreducible unitary representation of $G$.

Take an irreducible unitary representation $(\pi, V)$ of $G$, and assume it has a $K$-fixed vector $v$. Suppose you have an embedding $V \to L^2(X)$ and define $\phi$ to be the image of $v$ by this embedding. Is it necessarily an eigenfunction of $\Delta$? That would mean that the unitary irreducible representations of $G$ (with a $K$-fixed vector and an embedding in $L^2(X)$)  exactly correspond to eigenfunctions of $\Delta$. Does it have a meaning in the setting of more general groups?

Comment: $G$ does not have any compact open subgroup. Moreover, a Laplace eigenfunction only generates an irreducible unitary representation of $G$ if it is also a Hecke eigenform. Finally, $G$ should act on the right inside $\phi$ in order to maintain left $\Gamma$-invariance. I recommend that you read a standard textbook (e.g. Bump: Automorphic forms and representatiions, or Goldfeld-Hundley: Automorphic Representations and $L$-Functions for the General Linear Group I-II).